# On a certain symmetric ball problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have $12$ boxes and there are $9$ balls and seven are blue and two are black. The black balls are always placed $6$ from each other with position of first black ball picked randomly. For example if one black ball is in first box then second one is in seventh position.

What is the probability that if we assign the remaining seven balls randomly all seven lie between the two black balls (including together with the two black balls)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are five valid boxes, and twelve in total, the probability of all balls being in between the two black balls simply equals:

$$\left(\frac{5}{12}\right)^7 \approx 0.00218$$

Edit after the OP changed the question:

$$\left(\frac{7}{12}\right)^7 \approx 0.02298$$

Edit after the OP clarified that the boxes are placed in a circle. There are two sets of seven boxes which can be used by the blue balls. We can add all possible combinations for each of the two sets, but must subtract combinations which are counted twice (i.e., where the blue balls are only put in boxes which contain a black ball). We find:

$$\frac{7^7 + 7^7 - 2^7}{12^7} \approx 0.04596$$

Comment: Well you are fixing the two black balls. The black balls are also randomly placed.

Comment: @Brout It doesn't matter where they are placed: there are always five boxes between the two balls.

Comment: I was thinking following. Pick the two black balls and pick one blue. Then the odds remaining $6$ blue balls are on same side as first blue ball is $(7/12)^6$ and so answer is not $(7/12)^7$.

Comment: @Brout What "side" are you talking about? All blue balls must be in between the boxes containing the two black balls.

Comment: Suppose two black balls are in first and seventh position. Then side means $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ or $\{7,8,9,10,11,12,1\}$.

Comment: @Brout You might want to clarify this is in your original post. I edited my answer according to this new information.

Comment: +1 for being super-accomodating to the OP which keeps changing the question. :)